# Setting ngTrueValue and ngFalseValue to numbers

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angular-ngmodel

**Update**: question is obsolete for latest Angular version, see tsh's comment on this post

---

I have bound a checkbox to a value:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" />
```

The value of the checkbox is set to 1 in the controller:

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.checkbox = 1
}
```

However, initially the checkbox does not appear checked. If I change the initial value of `$scope.checkbox` to `"1"`, it does. ([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qHxww/))

I have tried all kinds of variations:

```
ng-true-value="{{1}}"
ng-true-value="{{Number(1)}}"
ng-true-value="{{parseInt('1')}}"
```

None of them work. How can I make angular treat the arguments as a number?

Comment: Sorry I should have added more... check it again

Comment: if you change the scope select to '1', it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/fergnab/wfefmyex/1/

Comment: Notice for new comers: This question is out of date since `ng-true-value` had been changed to an expression, and everything should works as OP expected with a newer (but not quite new) version of angular. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3pbb77h/)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use [**ngChecked**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angChecked), If the expression is truthy, then special attribute "checked" will be set on the element

```
<input type="checkbox" 
    ng-model="checkbox" 
    ng-true-value="1" 
    ng-false-value="0" 
    ng-checked="checkbox == 1" />
```

And you can use `$scope.$watch` to convert it to number

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return $scope.checkbox;
}, function(){
    $scope.checkbox = Number($scope.checkbox);
    console.log($scope.checkbox, typeof $scope.checkbox);
},true);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/69CAF/1/)

Comment: You do not need ng-true-value or ng-false-value with this approach

Comment: Thank you, `ng-checked="checkbox == 1"` worked perfectly

Comment: If someone will be having similar problem, than one can use ng-true-value="'1'" - as it is in the docs. Besides, as far as I know, ngChecked and ngModel shouldn't be used together

Comment: Doesn't this lead to undefined behavior? The documentation of `ngChecked` warns: "Note that this directive should not be used together with `ngModel`, as this can lead to unexpected behavior."

Answer (score 6):

I have created directive for that, seems to work fine:

```
angular.module('app').directive('cdTrueValue', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(v){
        return v ? scope.$eval(attrs.cdTrueValue) : scope.$eval(attrs.cdFalseValue);
      });

      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
          return value === scope.$eval(attrs.cdTrueValue);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Usage:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox" cd-true-value="1" cd-false-value="0" />
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/enh3vuk7/)**

Comment: add `ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) { return value === scope.$eval(attrs.cdTrueValue); });` inside the link function to have it display the correct checkbox status when loading a value from the model

Comment: @Luke Thanks, have you tested it?

Comment: I have. The only issue i found is that the directive must be named something that is `< 'input'`, otherwise angular processes the directives in the wrong order and the parser and formatter are created in the wrong order. So in your example `'cdTrueValue' < 'input' === true` and it works. But if you called it `'xxTrueValue'` things are created in the wrong order and it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

HTML attributes do not have any types. They can not contain anything else, then a string, so it is always a string. End of story.

You can not differentiate between between `1` and `"1"` in an HTML attribute. Angular tries to keep up with that, so only strings will work.

Comment: `<input type="number">`

Answer (score 0):

The first approach above is great. That's works fine. You can also use ng-change directive if you need use dynamic model (e.g. linked with ID or number - in case you wanna work with ID you don't know ahead). Just pass model as parameter: ng-change="fooBar(model[ID])" , catch in controller function and use Number(model[ID]) re-type. That's convert true as 1, false as 0 and you can work with this.