# ng-true-value='0' picking up wrong values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

For demo see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wYfs4/646/) here and click on the `Out of Stock` checkbox.

It should only show stock with quantity of 0, but it is also picking up quantity of 30. I think this is becasue it is matching against string values.

I assume issue is with:

```
ng-true-value='0'
```

What is best way to fix this? Please can you provide code example?

Comment: Should only show 0 qty - therefore out of stock.

Comment: Check out this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192440/setting-ngtruevalue-and-ngfalsevalue-to-numbers

Comment: @Rambler thats for showing if checkbox should be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make strict value dynamic:

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in inventory | filter: searchInventory:!!searchInventory.qty | orderBy:sortOrder">
```

Note: this might get messy if you have multiple similar criterias

http://jsfiddle.net/wYfs4/648/

Answer (score 1):

Per [filter docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) you need to add additional argument (comparator) for strict comparisons

Try changing:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in inventory | filter: searchInventory | orderBy:sortOrder">
```

To

```
<div ng-repeat="item in inventory | filter: searchInventory:true | orderBy:sortOrder">
```

Comment: Thanks, does help - but issue with that is that it does not go back to the full list when the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Might need to use custom filter function

Answer (score 1):

Because of `filter` also return partially matching data so when you compared with quantity `0` then also matched with `30` because it also contained `0`.

you can use exact matching using `true` in filter like: `filter: searchInventory: true`.

can active exact matching for only `qty` by some tricky . when use `true` act as exact matching and when use `false` not exact matching so use `true` for only 'qty = 0'.

can try :

in controller add another function and variable

```
$scope.exactMatching = false; // initially set false

  $scope.changeStockFilter = function() { // this function call on change checkbox value
    if($scope.searchInventory.qty === '0') {
        $scope.exactMatching = true; // if qty 0 then set true
    } else {
       $scope.exactMatching = false;
    }
  };
```

and in html:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='searchInventory.qty' data-ng-true-value="'0'" data-ng-false-value='' ng-change="changeStockFilter()"> Out of Stock
</div>
```

and

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in inventory | filter: searchInventory : exactMatching | orderBy:sortOrder">
```

[PLUNKER DEMO LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/YN8Uhz3IRIBFshMPVR7b?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but it works:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='searchInventory.qty' data-ng-true-value="0" data-ng-false-value='!0||0'> Out of Stock
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='searchInventory.status' data-ng-true-value='inactive' data-ng-false-value='!inactive || inactive'> Inactive

<div ng-repeat="item in inventory | filter: searchInventory:true | orderBy:sortOrder">
```