# AngularJS: ng-checked with ng-model, what are caveats?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have came across the same problem as it described in this question: [Setting ngTrueValue and ngFalseValue to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192440/setting-ngtruevalue-and-ngfalsevalue-to-numbers)

The solution, suggested in the accepted answer, *does* really work fine. But it combines `ng-checked` and `ng-model` directives together.

In the current question I want to focus on this problem. As the [documentation states](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked):

> Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as
>   this can lead to unexpected behavior.

My question is not a duplicate of the mentioned above, because I am rising a more general question: what are caveats of this approach, against which the documentation warns?

What exact *unexpected behaviour* it can lead to and under which circumstances?

Comment: It's probably not helping but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yhfaggh5/3/) is a weird behavior if you use booth (but it's also a weird use of those directives) or maybe they are talking about [this use](http://jsfiddle.net/yhfaggh5/1/) a the too directives

Comment: Curious example, thanks